# How to strip dylib

Tags: macos, operating-system, strip

I want to strip dylib. How can it be done?

Like on Linux, `strip -strip--unneeded * so` command works.

But on mac, what is command to strip dylib or reduce size of dylib?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732979/hiding-the-symbols-of-a-static-library-in-a-dynamic-library-in-mac-os-x and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793325/hiding-symbols-in-a-shared-library-on-mac-os-x and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236525/cant-strip-all-unneeded-symbols-on-a-mac-os-x-c-application seem relevant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trim whitespace (including tabs)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs)

Comment: This will help me to ask a query on stackoverflow  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask